# Installing Ganache GUI on windows 8.1

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache

How to install Ganache UI on windows 8.1 ?
I downloaded from Official website but after downloading i am unable to install it on my machine.

I tried to install it through power shell but facing following error :

[image]

Please provide a step to step guide if anyone knows.
Thanks

Comment: What errors are you running into? Can you share further details? Have you tried `add-appxpackage \path\to\ganache.appx` in PowerShell? See [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-windows-8-apps-without-storewindows-8/)

Answer (score 0):

For Window 7,8,8.1 users try to download the version listed in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Nmx.png) image

It is the older version so may be there are some bugs but it can help you for basic functionalities.